# DAX DateDiff with slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

Need help with DAX Syntax in what I am trying to accomplish. Here is what I have currently tried

> Number of Months  = ABS(DATEDIFF(myLeas[RENTDATE],TODAY(),Month))

The Problem is, in place of "Today" i need to pass the date coming from the Slicer on the visual. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `TODAY()` with:

```
SELECTEDVALUE ( Table[Column] )
```

where Table[Column] is the column you have put on the slicer.

So your measure will be:

```
Number of Months =
ABS (
    DATEDIFF (
        myLeas[RENTDATE],
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Table[Column] ),
        MONTH
    )
)
```

Search for additional tips:
[capture slicer value pbi](https://www.google.com/search?q=capture%20slicer%20value%20pbi&rlz=1C1GCEB_enPL844PL845&oq=capture%20slicer%20value%20pbi&aqs=chrome..69i57.7432j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

For further tips:

https://powerpivotpro.com/2018/02/using-selectedvalues-capture-power-bi-slicer-selections/

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a date slicer, you probably have start and end dates. In this case `SELECTEDVALUE` might not work. You could try using variables in this case:

```
Months = 
VAR MAX_DATE = MAXX(ALLSELECTED(myLeas),myLeas[RentDate])
Return ABS(DATEDIFF(Table[RentDate],MAX_DATE,MONTH))
```

This should give the value you are looking for. Hope this helps.